# Join seven files with awk line-by-line

Tags: awk, join

I have seven (or eight and so on) files with same number of lines.

file1

```
1.001
1.002
1.003
1.004
```

file2

```
2.001
2.002
2.003
2.004
```

file3

```
3.001
3.002
3.003
3.004
```

etc.

Desired output:

```
1.001;2.001;3.001;4.001;5.001;6.001;7.001
1.002;2.002;3.002;4.002;5.002;6.002;7.002
1.003;2.003;3.003;4.003;5.003;6.003;7.003
1.004;2.004;3.004;4.004;5.004;6.004;7.004
```

How to do it with short script in awk?

Comment: Why not just something like `paste -d\; file{1..8}` or `paste -d\; file*`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As steeldriver said, the reasonable way to do this is with `paste`:

```
$ paste -d';' file*
1.001;2.001;3.001;4.001;5.001;6.001;7.001;8.001
1.002;2.002;3.002;4.002;5.002;6.002;7.002;8.002
1.003;2.003;3.003;4.003;5.003;6.003;7.003;8.003
1.004;2.004;3.004;4.004;5.004;6.004;7.004;8.004
```

But, if you must use `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR](FNR==NR?"":";")$0} END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' file*
1.001;2.001;3.001;4.001;5.001;6.001;7.001;8.001
1.002;2.002;3.002;4.002;5.002;6.002;7.002;8.002
1.003;2.003;3.003;4.003;5.003;6.003;7.003;8.003
1.004;2.004;3.004;4.004;5.004;6.004;7.004;8.004
```

The awk script keeps all the data in memory.  If the files are large, this could be a problem.  But, for this task, `paste` is better and simpler anyway.

#### How it works

In this script `a` is an array with `a[i]` being the output for line `i`.  As we read through each of the subsequent files, we append the new information for line `i` to the end of `a[i]`.  After we have finished reading the files, we print out the values in `a`.  In more detail:

- `a[FNR]=a[FNR](FNR==NR?"":";")$0`

  `FNR` is the line number of the current file we are reading and `$0` are the contents of that line.  This code adds `$0` on to the end of `a[FNR]`.  Except if we are still reading the first file, we put in a semicolon before `$0`.  This is done using the complex looking ternary statement: `(FNR==NR?"":";")`.  This is really just a if-then-else command.  If we are reading the first file, that is if `FNR==NR`, then it returns an empty string `""`.  If not, it returns a semicolon, `;`.
- `END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}`

  After we have finished reading all the files, this prints out the data that we have accumulated in array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX Awk; this works with an arbitrary amount of files, and the files don’t
even have to have the same amount of lines. The script keeps going until all
files are out of lines:

```perl
BEGIN {
  do {
    br = ch = 0
    while (++ch < ARGC)
      if (getline < ARGV[ch]) {
        printf ch < ARGC - 1 ? $0 ";" : $0 RS
        br = 1
      }
  } while (br)
}
```